# How to delegate to a shortcode function in order to filter pod items created by the current user using Pods Framework in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, podscms

I want to list some pod items on front end. To do this I am normally using `pods` shortcode. To filter the data I use `where` attribute inside pods shortcode. For example:

```
[pods name="salon" where="author.ID = '2'"]
    <li>{@name}</li>
[/pods]
```

I want to filter pod items by the `author.ID`. The user should see the pod items that are created by himself. It is possible to access the current user by wordpress api 
`global $current_user;`. Also it is possible to get it by using magic tags of Pods `{@user.ID}`.

But the problem is I cannot use php code or magic tags inside shortcode such as this:

```
[pods name="salon" where="author.ID = '{@user.ID}'"]
```

I am looking for a way to overcome this problem.

I thought maybe I can write a new shortcode function where I can get the current user's id and then call the `pods` shortcode function such as this:

```
function pods_by_current_user($atts) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    // put it into 'where' attribute and delegate to the "pods" function
```

Do you think that this is the right way to solve this problem? And do you know how to  put `$user_id` into `$atts` and delegate the rest to the actual `pods` shortcode function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pods_by_current_user function, try doing:

`$atts[ 'where' ] = 'author.ID = ' . (int) $user_id;`

and then return the normal Pods shortcode:

`return pods_shortcode( $atts );`

This will let you use any of the normal [pods] shortcode attributes as usual, but will set the 'where' to automatically limit to the current user ID. I'm sure you can make this more complex, but that will do what you're after.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. This worked indeed. Just I need to add one small correction. The call to the delegated function should include `$content` variable `return pods_shortcode( $atts, $content );` thus the new shortcode function's declaration should be: `function pods_by_current_user($atts, $content = null)`